# Getting return value of oracle function with python

Tags: python, oracle

I have a PL/SQL function in my oracle database which returns a custom type which is a table of numbers. Running this function within a sql console works fine.

What's the correct way to get the result within a python script?

For build-in type I can do something like this:

```py
return_value = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
cursor.callfunc("myfunction", return_value, [list_of_params])
```

But I have no idea how to handle custom types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a function returns a  custom type which is a nested table or varray, then it's ideal to read the values using `TABLE` function.

Assuming that your function definition is something like

```
create or replace function "myfunction"(p_in1 int, p_in2 varchar2) 
  return my_custom_type AS
  ..
  ..
```

You may do this and fetch results like any other query result. You don't have to pass the type name as well.

```
cursor.execute("""select * from TABLE( "myfunction"(:p_in1,:p_in2))""", (1,'TEXT') )
```

Comment: That looks very promising. Will test it tomorrow. Thanks a lot!